# Cambio de html entre escritorio y safari movil

Tags: html, ios, safari

Estoy programando una página y en cierta sección tiene un p para colocar dos números de teléfono. Sin embargo, cuando abro la página en safari en iphone, el html tiene un a href de más, que yo no escribí. del lado izquierdo está el código en móvil y del derecho en escritorio que es el que yo escribí[image]

alguien tiene idea de qué pasa?
Gracias

Answer (score 2):

en iOS Safary detecta la existencia de telefonos y les agrega ese `href` esto lo hace para que sea mas facil llamar directamente.

Si lo que buscas es que esto no te pase solo debes setearlo en el head de esta forma:

```
<head>
  ...
  <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
</head>
```

Aca te dejo la [documentacion oficial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html) tambien